# Center the Top Down Camera on 65 Degrees

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, angle, topdown

I am devoloping a TopDown-Shooter with Unity. The camera to follow the player got its transform

- position: 0,20,0
- rotation: 65,0,0

The camera is using this simple follow command:

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(playerTransform.position.x, transform.position.y, playerTransform.position.z);
}
```

Because of the fact, that the camera is rotated by 65 degrees on the x - Axis, the camera is not centered anymore.

[Ingame View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsElh.png)

What do i have to calculate in the script, to center the camera back to the middle?

To fix my problem I could set the camera on (0,20,-10), but I need it calculated because it will jump back if it is not calculated in the Update.

At the moment I am just calculating -20 on the z Axis in the script:

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(playerTransform.position.x, transform.position.y, playerTransform.position.z - 20);
}
```

and I want to replace this value with a correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your scene as a right-triangle with the camera's line-of-sight pointing down the hypotenuse ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwGpC.jpg)).  We know the height of the camera off the ground, 20 units, and we know the angle the camera makes relative to vertical, 35 degrees (90 - 65 = 35). Now we just need to solve for the horizontal distance X.

Our equation will we be:

```
Tan(35 degrees) = X / 20
X = Tan(35 degrees) * 20
X = 14.004...
```

So your guess of 10 wasn't too far off. To put this into code you get:

```
private void Update()
{
    float zDistance = Mathf.Tan(transform.eulerAngles.X * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * 20;
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        playerTransform.position.x, 
        transform.position.y, 
        playerTransform.position.z - zDistance);
}
```

If your camera angle won't change then zDistance won't change and you can just calculate it once in `Start()`.